# In simple english can anyone explain why and when to use the never type?

Tags: typescript

I've been struggling to understand when to use the never type, so can anyone explain and give some scenarios when to use the never type? I've read about it being use in endless loops and stuff but, still don't quite get it. can anyone explain when to use the never type and in what scenario?

I couldn't wrap my head around the concept, I've tried reading blogs and articles, I just can see where should i use it.

Comment: I've used never when doing conditional types before.  If prop X is present, y shouldn't be present sort of thing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may have more luck if you give up trying to find a reason for `never` and simply exploit the rules of the game. `never` is used all over the place for different reasons, it is a multi-purpose tool. You will find use cases as you go when doing type-level programming.

Properties:

- `never` extends everything
- only `never` and `any` extend `never`
- `never & T` is `never`
- `never | T` is `T`

Some quirks:

- `any extends never ? X : Y` is `X | Y`
- `[any] extends [never] ? X : Y` is `Y`
- `T extends U ? X : Y` is `never` if `T` is never
- `[T] extends [U] ? X : Y` is what you expect depending on `U`

An example of a way to exploit these properties: knowing that `never | T` is `T`, if you are constructing a union and you want to filter out some of its members, you will intentionally produce `never` values expecting that they will be swallowed later.

For user-facing types, a rule of thumb is simply to avoid using `never` and `any` as values, but to use them as constraints or parameter types. `never` then becomes a cheap way to forbid a value. For example:

- if you want to forbid objects containing the key `foo`: write `{ foo?: never }` as a constraint or parameter type.
- if you want to reject certain inputs but you can't think of a type definition: write a utility type that returns `never` when the input doesn't meet your requirements: `<A extends Check<A>>(a: A) => whatever` (where `Check<T>` may return `never`)